# Using escaped selectors in Sass maps

Tags: css, sass

In our CSS we have escaped characters in our selectors using `\` like so:

```
.width-1\.5 { width: 1.5rem; }
.width-1\/2 { width: 50%; }
```

So this allows us to have CSS classes like: `class="width-1/2"`

And we store all of these values in Sass maps like:

`$widths: (1\.5: 1.5rem, 1\/2: 50%);`

And then we create the CSS with a simple loop:

```
@each $key,
$value in $widths {
    .width-#{$key}: $value
}
```

However we get the error: `SassError: 1\/2 isn't a valid CSS value.`

So it's fine with `\.` but it doesn't like: `\/`. Even though outside of Sass it's fine to use this syntax to escape the `/`.

If we wrap the keys in quotes in the map like this:
`$widths: ('1\.5': 1.5rem, '1\/2': 50%);`

Sass removes the escape character so it becomes just `1/2` and therefore an invalid CSS selector with: `SassError: Invalid CSS after ".width-1": expected selector, was "/2"`.

How can we create this syntax using Sass maps?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use the `quote` function:

`$widths: (quote(1\/2): 50%);`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work by double-escaping the punctuation. E.g.:

```
$widths: (
  '1\\.5': 1.5rem
)
```

For what it's worth, I'm using the [sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass) NPM package. Not sure if there's a discrepancy between Dart Sass, `node-sass`, or other implementations that would affect whether this works or not.